# How many natural numbers less than $10^8$ are there, whose sum of digits equals $7$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many natural numbers less than $10^8$ are there, whose sum of digits equals $7$?

[I got it here.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100208012016AAICOHI)But is there any more effecient and easier way to solve than the link shows?

Comment: Generating functions?

Comment: Well, you can skip all numbers in the set {$710,000,999,999$}

Comment: @user99680, pardon, I can't understand!

Comment: @Sush: Just saying that the sum of digits of numbers in this set, together with the set {$7.100.000, 7.100.001,...., 9.999.999$} will be larger than $8$. Sorry, I should have used dots and commas, to avoid confusion. Maybe this will make the search a bit easier.

Comment: `you can skip all numbers in the set {710,000,999,999}` you mean to skip these 4 numbers only? Out of 10^8, why is skipping 4 numbers is important? And a mathematical set can not have duplicate values in it. So your set should be `{710,000,999}`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to  say, skip _Every_ natural number in the interval 710.000<n <999.999: $n $ in $]mathbb N$. For example: neither of : 71, 72, 73, 74,...,99 will work, since the sum of digits here will be $\geq 8$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The numbers have 8 places (some of which might be zero), and there are 7 units of value to go into them.  (Each place can have at most 9 units, but that's automatic since there's only 7 units total.)  So it's a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem with 7 stars and 7 bars, making $\binom{14}{7} = 3432$ such numbers.

(For example, `|**|*|***|||*|` would correspond to the number 02130010.)

[edited: 8 places, not 7]

Answer (score 0):

C++ program for your problem:

#include < iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int count=0;

int sum(int x);

for (int i=1;i<100000000;i++){

if (sum(i)==7)

```
count++;
```

}

cout < < count< < endl;

return 0;

}

int sum (int x){

int add=0;

```
while(x){

add=add+x%10;
x=x/10;
}
```

return add;
}